# Backing up SQLite database to external storage - Wrong file reference

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm getting a `ESDIR (is a directory)` error from the exception catch. I know it's because of something wrong with the paths that I've used and it seems that I'm referencing a folder rather than a file (maybe?), but I'm unsure how to correct it.

I've checked that the `.mkdirs` is working - I can see the files get created.

Edit: With suggestions.

```
private void exportDB(){

      try {
          String DB =getDatabasePath(DBHandler.DATABASE_NAME).toString();
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Path is: " +DB, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

          String sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Path is: " +sd, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

              String backupDBPath = sd + "/com.AH.memorisethai/Backup/database.db";
              File currentDB =(getDatabasePath(DBHandler.DATABASE_NAME));
              File backupDB = new File(backupDBPath);
              backupDB.mkdirs();

              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Path is: "+backupDBPath, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

              FileInputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(currentDB);
              FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(backupDBPath);
              FileChannel inChannel = inStream.getChannel();
              FileChannel outChannel = outStream.getChannel();
              inChannel.transferTo(0, inChannel.size(), outChannel);
              inStream.close();
              outStream.close();

      } catch (Exception e) {

          Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }

}
```

Error Log:

```
02-19 09:45:59.820: W/myApp(22243): Start Copy
02-19 09:45:59.825: W/System.err(22243): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/com.AH.memorisethai/Backup/database.db: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)
02-19 09:45:59.825: W/System.err(22243):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:409)
02-19 09:45:59.825: W/System.err(22243):    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:88)
02-19 09:45:59.825: W/System.err(22243):    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:128)
02-19 09:45:59.830: W/System.err(22243):    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:117)
02-19 09:45:59.830: W/System.err(22243):    at com.AH.memorisethai.MainMenu.exportDB(MainMenu.java:44)
02-19 09:45:59.830: W/System.err(22243):    at com.AH.memorisethai.MainMenu.onCreate(MainMenu.java:23)
02-19 09:45:59.830: W/System.err(22243):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
02-19 09:45:59.830: W/System.err(22243):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
02-19 09:45:59.830: W/System.err(22243):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
02-19 09:45:59.830: W/System.err(22243):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
02-19 09:45:59.830: W/System.err(22243):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
02-19 09:45:59.830: W/System.err(22243):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
02-19 09:45:59.830: W/System.err(22243):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-19 09:45:59.830: W/System.err(22243):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
02-19 09:45:59.830: W/System.err(22243):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
02-19 09:45:59.830: W/System.err(22243):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-19 09:45:59.830: W/System.err(22243):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
02-19 09:45:59.830: W/System.err(22243):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
02-19 09:45:59.830: W/System.err(22243):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
02-19 09:45:59.830: W/System.err(22243):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-19 09:45:59.830: W/System.err(22243): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)
02-19 09:45:59.830: W/System.err(22243):    at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
02-19 09:45:59.830: W/System.err(22243):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
02-19 09:45:59.830: W/System.err(22243):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:393)
02-19 09:45:59.835: W/System.err(22243):    ... 19 more
```

Following the feedback received I have altered the code so there are separate `File` variables for the directory path and the file path. I've also added in checks to ensure files/folders are there:

```
private void exportDB(){

      try {
          File DB =getDatabasePath(DBHandler.DATABASE_NAME);
          if (DB.isFile()){
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File isFile: " +DB, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              Log.w("myApp", "File:"+DB);
          } else if (DB.isDirectory()){
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Folder isDirectory: " +DB, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              Log.w("myApp", "Folder:"+DB);
          }

          File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Path is: " +sd, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          File backupDBFolder = new File(sd, "/com.AH.memorisethai/Backup/");
          File backupDBFile = new File(sd, "/com.AH.memorisethai/Backup/database.db");
          backupDBFolder.mkdirs();

          if (backupDBFolder.isDirectory()){
              Log.w("myApp","External folder isDirectory: "+backupDBFolder);
          } else{
              Log.w("myApp","Nothing found");
          }


           Log.w("myApp", "Start Copy");
           FileInputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(DB);
           FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(backupDBFile);

           FileChannel inChannel = inStream.getChannel();
           FileChannel outChannel = outStream.getChannel();
           inChannel.transferTo(0, inChannel.size(), outChannel);
           inStream.close();
           outStream.close();
           Log.w("myApp", "End Copy");

      } catch (Exception e) {

          e.printStackTrace();
          //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }

}
```

Then I get the following from the Logcat:

```
02-19 12:00:51.468: W/myApp(9243): File:/data/data/com.AH.memorisethai/databases/wordsmanager
02-19 12:00:51.483: W/myApp(9243): External folder isDirectory: /storage/emulated/0/com.AH.memorisethai/Backup
02-19 12:00:51.483: W/myApp(9243): Start Copy
02-19 12:00:51.483: W/System.err(9243): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/com.AH.memorisethai/Backup/database.db: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)
02-19 12:00:51.488: W/System.err(9243):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:409)
02-19 12:00:51.488: W/System.err(9243):     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:88)
02-19 12:00:51.488: W/System.err(9243):     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:73)
02-19 12:00:51.488: W/System.err(9243):     at com.AH.memorisethai.MainMenu.exportDB(MainMenu.java:53)
02-19 12:00:51.488: W/System.err(9243):     at com.AH.memorisethai.MainMenu.onCreate(MainMenu.java:23)
02-19 12:00:51.488: W/System.err(9243):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
02-19 12:00:51.488: W/System.err(9243):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
02-19 12:00:51.488: W/System.err(9243):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
02-19 12:00:51.488: W/System.err(9243):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
02-19 12:00:51.488: W/System.err(9243):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
02-19 12:00:51.488: W/System.err(9243):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
02-19 12:00:51.488: W/System.err(9243):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-19 12:00:51.488: W/System.err(9243):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
02-19 12:00:51.488: W/System.err(9243):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
02-19 12:00:51.488: W/System.err(9243):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-19 12:00:51.488: W/System.err(9243):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
02-19 12:00:51.488: W/System.err(9243):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
02-19 12:00:51.488: W/System.err(9243):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
02-19 12:00:51.488: W/System.err(9243):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-19 12:00:51.488: W/System.err(9243): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)
02-19 12:00:51.493: W/System.err(9243):     at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
02-19 12:00:51.493: W/System.err(9243):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
02-19 12:00:51.493: W/System.err(9243):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:393)
02-19 12:00:51.493: W/System.err(9243):     ... 18 more
```

So despite using the separate variable for the file path it still believes it is a directory?

Comment: Where is the filename in your backupdbpath?

Comment: I've added /database.db to the end of the backup db path, but still the same problem

Comment: The error changed to file not found exception

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:**

So, your LogCat error report saying that the following path isn't a file but a directory.

```
/storage/emulated/0/com.AH.memorisethai/Backup/database.db
```

That's why when you are passing this path in the following line then its throwing `java.io.FileNotFoundException` error.

```
FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(backupDBPath);
```

I think, now you get that where the problem is. So, you have to make sure that when you passing a path to  `FileOutputStream()` constructor, then its a file not a directory.

The solution can be as...assume, you are trying to backup your `Database` in a `Text.txt` file then the your corrected code should be as follows....

```
String backupDBPath = sd + "/com.AH.memorisethai/Backup/database.db";
File backupDirectory = new File(backupDBPath);
backupDirectory.mkdirs();

String backupFilePath = backupDBPath + "/" + "Text.txt";
File backupFile = new File(backupFilePath);

FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(backupFile);
```

This will solve your all problem.

Comment: I've edited the code so that the getExternalStorageDirectory() goes toString() before being saved as SD, but I have the same result.

Comment: then you should post the `LogCat` error report. Without that its hard say anything.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure how to filter the LogCat report to show anything meaningful. The error doesn't seem to be turning up there since it is shown in the exception.

Comment: `catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace(); 
}` like this place the `e.printStackTrace();` into your `catch` block which will print the error details into `LogCat`. Then copy the error log from `LogCat` and paste that here.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to get the log out (see updated post for details)

Comment: so, which line is 44th line in you `MainMenu.java` class?

Comment: Hi Hamid, I've updated my code (see edit at bottom of the code) to include tests that the directory/files are correct and implemented different paths for folder creation and file creation, but I'm still getting the error

Comment: I think, you didn't follow my suggestion. I posted my updated answer after insuring that it doesn't produce any error. Please, checkout my updated answer carefully.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have to create the directory without the filname and copy the file with the filename.

```
private void exportDB(){

  try {
      String DB =getDatabasePath(DBHandler.DATABASE_NAME).toString();
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Path is: " +DB, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

      String sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Path is: " +sd, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

          String backupDBPath = sd + "/com.AH.memorisethai/Backup/";
          String backupDBFile = sd + "/com.AH.memorisethai/Backup/database.db";
          File currentDB =(getDatabasePath(DBHandler.DATABASE_NAME));
          File backupDB = new File(backupDBPath);
          File backupFile = new File(backupDBFile);
          backupDB.mkdirs();

          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Path is: "+backupDBPath, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

          FileInputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(currentDB);
          FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(backupFile);
          FileChannel inChannel = inStream.getChannel();
          FileChannel outChannel = outStream.getChannel();
          inChannel.transferTo(0, inChannel.size(), outChannel);
          inStream.close();
          outStream.close();

  } catch (Exception e) {

      Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
```

}

Comment: Updated my answer. I forgot to make a file out of the path.